# How to version-control a set of input data along with its processing scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, git, version-control

I am working with a set of Python scripts that take data from an Excel file that is set up to behave as a pseudo-database. Excel is used instead of an SQL software due to compatibility and access requipements for other people I work with who aren't familiar with databases.

I have a set of about 10 tables with multiple records in each and relational keys linking them all (again in a pseudo-linking kind of way, using some flimsy data validation).

The scripts I am using are version controlled by Git, and I know the pitfalls of adding a `.xlsx` file to a repo, so I have kept it away. Since the data is a bit vulnerable, I want to make sure I have a way of keeping track of any changes we make to it. My thought was to have a script that breaks the Excel file into `.csv` tables and adds those to the repo, i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
excel_input_file = Path(r"<...>")
output_path = Path(r"<...>")
tables_dict = pd.read_excel(excel_input_file, sheet_name=None)

for i,x in tables_dict.items():
    x.to_csv(output_path / (i+'.csv'), index=False)
```

Would this be a typically good method for keeping track of the input files at each stage?

Answer (score 0):

Git tends to work better with text files rather than binary files, as you've noted, so this would be a better choice than just checking in an Excel file. Specifically, Git would be able to merge and diff these files, whereas they couldn't be merged natively by Git otherwise.

Typically the way that people handle this sort of situation is to take one or more plain text input files (e.g., CSV or SQL) and then build them into the usable output format (e.g., Excel or database) as part of the build or test step, depending on where they're needed. I've done similar things by using a Git fast-export dump to create test Git repositories, and it generally works well.

If you had just one input file, which you don't in this case, you could also use smudge and clean filters to turn the source file in the repository into a different format in the checkout. You can read about this with `man gitattributes`.